# Excel macro file saving through ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to create an Excel macro file and download it.

For example, I have a predefined template `test.xlsm` and in this I have 2 sheets. I want to add some data into this spreadsheet in one of the sheets. For this I'm using the "FastExcel" library.

I'm able to write the file. But I'm not able to save the file.